# CSS: still image when scrolling but content below to go above it

Tags: jquery, html, css

Right now this is what happens when a user scrolls my page:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mtuy1E5JPew

And [**here**](http://ffio.it/longobardi/index3.html)'s the page live.

As you can see, `img#intro` (the big B/W image) scrolls "normally". I'd like to have this movement instead (the 2 images are consequent):

[image: First]

[image: Second]

As you can see the B/W image stays still but the content below goes up and covers it.

Here's how the elements are placed (easy scheme):

```
<div id="container">
    <img ... />
    <img ... />
    <img src="" id="intro" /> <--- THIS IS THE B/W IMAGE!

    CONTENT BELOW
</div>
```

Here's relevant CSS:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:1305px;
    height:910px;
}

#intro {
    margin-top:40px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:8px
}
```

Comment: can you put your css/jquery for this particular part in the question?

Comment: Done! I simplified my structure

Comment: hmm, give me a sec i'll create a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zpkKQ/31/, make the container relative and the text absolute not the image. (the jquery is for the span element, as i don't know what the element you're using for your text is.

Comment: Mmmh that's not what I meant. I know how to position text over another element.. I'm trying to make the image fixed and having the content below to cover it while scrolling. Look at the 2 images, they're consequent. As you can see the window remains still, it's like the vertical canvas of the image reduces proportionally to the scroll. The other elements scroll normally, but the image stays still until it's covered by the content below scrolling.... hope it's not too convolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking at having a `fixed` position image while your content that you want to "go above it" is `relative` position with a higher `z-index`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/monL8tbx/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x300" class="fixed"/>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
        content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed-container {
    height: 300px;
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
}
.overlay {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    background: red;
    width: 1000px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```